# navigate one page to another in index.html page via angular js

Tags: javascript, java, html, sql, angularjs

I am trying to navigate from my index.html page to customer.html page. I want to do this via angular js as I am using angular framework. Currently I am navigating via html link, but I have to do this via angular. The functions that I want to use in customer.html page is not working because of that. 
This is my code:
HTML code: index.html:

```
        <body data-ng-controller="FirstCtrl as fctrl">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nishinda's Diner</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->
                     <li><a href="/api/first/customer">Customer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ownerLogIn.html">Owner</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
     </nav>

<body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl as mctrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a href="index.html">Nishinda's Diner</a></li>

                <li><a href="customer.html">Guest</a></li>
                <li><a href="ownerLogIn.html">Owner</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div>
```

These 2 are my Controller in angular JS:
first-ctrl.js:

```
        angular.module('restaurantApp').controller('FirstCtrl',FirstController);
            FirstController.$inject=['$http']
            function FirstController($http){

                var fctrl = this;

            fctrl.customer= function(){

                $http({                         
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'api/first/customer',

                        }).success(function(url){
                            console.log(url);
                            //mctrl.newCustomer=null;
                                }).error(function(error){

                                    console.log(error);                 

                                });
                    };

            }
```

This is my main-ctrl.js(for customer page):
                angular.module('restaurantApp').controller('FirstCtrl',FirstController).controller('MainCtrl', MainController);

```
        //injecting annotation=$http
    MainController.$inject=['$http']
    function MainController($http){
        var mctrl = this;

        mctrl.addCustomer= function(){

        $http({

                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/first/customer/add',
                    data: mctrl.newCustomer
                }).success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    mctrl.newCustomer=null;

                    if(data.status == 'success')
                    {
                    mctrl.loggedIn= true;

                    }else{

                        mctrl.loggedIn= false;

                    }
                        }).error(function(error){

                            console.log(error);                 

                        });
            };



    }

These are my controller:
FirstController:(It will be used for index.html)


        @Path("/first")
        public class FirstController {
            @GET
            @Path("/customer")
            //@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            public AppResponse customerPage(@Context HttpServletRequest request){


                AppResponse resp = new AppResponse();
                // generating the common msg for successful/ unsuccessful connection

                return resp;

            }
        }
```

This is my CustomerController:
            @Path("/first/customer")
            public class CustomerController {

```
        @GET
        @Path("/all")
        //produce result in data exchange format
        //produce object from json data 
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         public AppResponse getAll(){


            AppResponse resp = new AppResponse();
            // generating the common msg for successful/ unsuccessful connection
            try {
                //if successful show list
                CustomerDAO customerDAO=new CustomerDAO();
                List<Customer> customerList=customerDAO.getAll();   
                resp.setPayload(customerList);

            } catch (AppException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp.setStatus(AppResponse.ERROR);
                resp.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            }

            //customerDAO.getAll();
            return resp;        
         }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `redirect using AngularJS`? are you searching for `ng-view` SPA kind of thing?

Comment: Yup. Exactly. I want to redirect using angularjs. I was using "customer.html" link in my index page. But after using it when I was trying to implement the functions in customer page, those were not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda difficult to answer since there are so many ways to do this, but look into https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router